# How to split string on brackets ")("?

Tags: java, regex, string, scala

Input:

```
val str="(2500 - Analytical Charge Percentage of Monitoring Structure (MS) type Sub-Business Unit (SSBU) : 803.130000000000000000)(388 - Monitoring Structure (MS) type Sub-Business Unit (SSBU) : JzCddaxT)"
```

Would want two bigger strings inside () as elements of an array.
In this case if we are splitting on ")(":

Expected Output:

```
arr(0) = "(2500 - Analytical Charge Percentage of Monitoring Structure (MS) type Sub-Business Unit (SSBU) : 803.130000000000000000"

arr(1) = "388 - Monitoring Structure (MS) type Sub-Business Unit (SSBU) : JzCddaxT)"
```

I am using  `str.split("[\\\\)\\\\(]")` but its not working.

Comment: If you want to split on ")(", not on a single bracket, then you should not put them in a character class. In other words, you should be using `split("\\)\\(")`.

Comment: Inside a character class, `)` and `(` don't have to be escaped.

Comment: Moreover, you could use `(?<=\\))(?=\\()` if you want the brackets not be removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```java
split("[\\)\\(]")
```

will split on a `(` *and* on a `)`, so this (abbreviated) text:

```java
"(2500 (MS) Unit (SSBU) : 803.13)(388 (MS) Unit (SSBU) : JzCddaxT)"
```

becomes this:

```java
["", "2500 ", "MS", " Unit ", "SSBU", " : 803.13", "", "388 ", "MS", " Unit ", "SSBU", " : JzCddaxT"]
```

which is obviously not what you want.

Since you seem to want to just split on the 2-character substring `")("`, don't use a `[ ]` character class.

```java
split("\\)\\(")
```

which will produce what you showed:

```java
["(2500 (MS) Unit (SSBU) : 803.13", "388 (MS) Unit (SSBU) : JzCddaxT)"]
```